# how to create the session id in magento server using soap services

Tags: ios, magento

I am working on an iOS project in Objective C++.
I have trouble with this functionality.

How to create a session id for magento server using soap web service?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:
You need to set apiUser and apiKey from magento backend. Once you are done than use it and you will get session string.

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://yourmagentositeurl.com/soap/api/?wsdl');

// If somestuff requires api authentification,
// then get a session token
$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');

$result = $client->call($session, 'somestuff.method');
// If you don't need the session anymore
$client->endSession($session);
```